# How annotate the Max value of two fields in a Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have a model `Client`, how do i annotate then sort, the Max of its two fields:

```
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model):
    uploaded_photo_at = models.DateTimeField()
    uploaded_document_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

The following:

```
Client.objects.annotate(
    latest_activity_at=Max('uploaded_photo_at', 'uploaded_document_at', output_field=DateTimeField())
).order_by('latest_activity_at')
```

Raises this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function max(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: ...oto_at", "clients_client"."uploaded_document_at", MAX("clien...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I am using Posgresql and Django 1.11, if that helps.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Thanks to Robert's answer i was able to find [`Greatest` class of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest).

The following works:

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest

Client.objects.annotate(
    latest_activity_at=Greatest('uploaded_photo_at', 'uploaded_document_at')
).order_by('latest_activity_at')
```

Comment: The official documentation mentioned that GREATEST's implementation depends on the SQL backend. I found the handling of "NULL" puzzling to me and had to write extra select for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use django **query extra** function

```
qs = Client.objects.extra(select={'output_field': 
                                 'GREATEST(uploaded_photo_at, uploaded_document_at)'})
                   .order_by('latest_activity_at')
```

This will return max value two fileds